# Increasing the size of the HTML body when responding to cases

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I am receiving the following error:

```
HTML Body: data value to large: <html>...(max-length=32000)
```

I tried adjusting the email body size:

Setup -> Object Manager -> Email Message -> HTML Body

It is a standard field and cannot be modified to 131,072 as you can do with other text fields in Salesforce.

What have others done to fix this issue? We want our team to send long-form emails in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce support can update this to 131,072 for you - you just need to open a case with them. You'll need to include the following:

- Your organization ID.
- The business need for this request.
- The specific limit change amount you need.

See their documentation here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334028&type=1&mode=1

As noted by [Sebastian Kessel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5620274/sebastian-kessel), the Salesforce documentation states: "This increase does not apply to List Emails since list email contents is limited up to 32,000 characters (hard coded)"

Comment: There is a caveat in that article: "This increase does not apply to List Emails since list email contents is limited up to 32,000 characters (hard coded)". Not sure if this applies to the OP's case but you should mention it